# Programmatically change input filter of term description on taxonomy_form_term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, forms, input-formats

I couldn't find anywhere on the admin UI where I can change the input filter for term's description field. I have tried using hook_form_alter, but wasn't successful.

```
function mymod_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id === 'taxonomy_form_term') {
    $form['description']['#format'] = 'full_html';
    $form['description']['#title'] = t('test');
  }
}
```

The title for the input field would change, but not the format, even though dpm result indicates that the correct key/value pair was used. Is it too late in the rendering process to change the format of the field?

Comment: Have you tried attaching an #after_build handler to the form? Sometimes you need an after build to change certain elements on a form.

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein, I tried attaching `#after_build` to the `$form`, and set the format of the description field on the function callback of `#after_build`. It is still not working though. I could manually change the input filter to other formats but I wish to set the default on page load.

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein, I ended up using javascript, which was added to $form['#attached'] to set the default selection after the page load.